# Using string to access datastore column

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Looked through the documentation and can't work this out.

Is it possible to access the attribute of an entity retrieved from the datastore with a string in Python on GAE?

Something like employee.name but employee.<>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this, if I understand you correctly:

```
getattr(MyModel, attrib_name)
```

which will retrieve the attribute `attrib_name`